# Activator.CreateInstance with string

Tags: c#, generics, activator

I'm trying to populate a generic List< T > from another List< U > where the field names match, something like the untested pseudocode below. Where I'm having problems is when T is a string, for instance, which has no parameterless constructor. I've tried adding a string directly to the result object, but this gives me the obvious error -- that a string is not of Type T. Any ideas of how to solve this issue? Thanks for any pointers.

```
    public static List<T> GetObjectList<T, U>(List<U> givenObjects)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();

        //Get the two object types so we can compare them.
        Type returnType = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] classFieldsOfReturnType = returnType.GetProperties(
           BindingFlags.Instance |
           BindingFlags.Static |
           BindingFlags.NonPublic |
           BindingFlags.Public);

        Type givenType = typeof(U);
        PropertyInfo[] classFieldsOfGivenType = givenType.GetProperties(
           BindingFlags.Instance |
           BindingFlags.Static |
           BindingFlags.NonPublic |
           BindingFlags.Public);

        //Go through each object to extract values
        foreach (var givenObject in givenObjects)
        {

            foreach (var field in classFieldsOfReturnType)
            {
                //Find where names match
                var givenTypeField = classFieldsOfGivenType.Where(w => w.Name == field.Name).FirstOrDefault();

                if (givenTypeField != null)
                {
                    //Set the value of the given object to the return object
                    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    var value = field.GetValue(givenObject);

                    PropertyInfo pi = returnType.GetProperty(field.Name);
                    pi.SetValue(instance, value);

                    result.Add(instance);
                }

            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: look at `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Use with caution!

Comment: Actually GetUninitializedObject does not work for strings in particular (`ArgumentException: Uninitialized Strings cannot be created`.) It should work for other classes without default constructor though, and I cannot really think of a reason to put a list of strings through this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` is `string` and you have already created custom code to convert your `givenObject` to a string, you just need to do an [intermediate cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) to `object` to add it to a `List<T>`:

```
    public static List<T> GetObjectList2<T, U>(List<U> givenObjects) where T : class
    {
        var result = new List<T>();

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            foreach (var givenObject in givenObjects)
            {
                var instance = givenObject.ToString();  // Your custom conversion to string.
                result.Add((T)(object)instance);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Proceed as before
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Incidentally, you are adding an `instance` of `T` to `result` for *every property* of `T` that matches a property name in `U` and for every item in `givenObjects`.  I.e. if `givenObjects` is a list of length 1 and `T` is a class with 10 matching properties, `result` could end up with 10 entries.  This looks wrong.  Also, you need to watch out for [indexed properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As an alternative to this approach, consider using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/), or serializing your `List<U>` to JSON with Json.NET then deserializing as a `List<T>`.

Comment: huh? cast does not change the type of underlying object, you can argue that if it's a value tape, that boxing may be considered type change, but for reference types it's quite clear cut. In other words if something gives you a run-time exception (as opposed to compile time error) then casting an object of a reference type is not going to fix that.

Comment: @zespri - Brent wrote " I've tried adding a string directly to the result object, but this gives me the obvious error -- that a string is not of Type T."  Thus Brent has already manually created a `string` corresponding to the input object, but the compiler is complaining because it can't be added to the `List<T>`  But `T` *is* `string`, so no real conversion is necessary, just a cast.

Comment: That worked, dbc, thanks! I did try casting the string to T, but that obviously didn't work. Your trick of casting the string to an object and then to T is really helpful. Good to know.

Comment: ok, let me upvote you then =) I missed that it was indeed compile time error.